# Some simple products not add in the Bundle Products

Tags: magento2.3.4, bundled-product, simple-product

I have to try to add some simple products into Bundle Products,
but whenever I search for that simple product is not display in the product listing.
I don't know why I have searched for any error, I have seen in the Logs, but in logs, there is no any kind of related entries to this issue.

Bundle Product SKU is : 0850DVD
Simple Product SKU is : 0850ADV,0850BDV,0850CDV,

please help with this, what should I miss in product configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the simple products that you are trying to assign to the bundle products have any custom options.

Because the simple products with the custom options will not be assignable to the bundle product.

Reference Link: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-bundle.html#things-to-remember

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, you are absolutely right, I have a simple product and its have the custom option to when I have removed that its working fine. thanks again.